# Check if a plane is around the same position/rotation as other

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two plane gameObject with the same scales. I am trying to achieve to see if the first moving plane comes around the position/rotation as the second static plane. It does not matter if the positions and rotations match or not, what matters is that it should come around the same value. For example, if the x position of plane 2 is 2.75, plane 1 should be matched with a value of 2. It should have an offset value to come at least near the second plane. How do I achieve this?

```
public class CheckIfFits: MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Plane_2;
    public float offset;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(this.transform.position == Plane_2.transform.position && this.transform.eulerAngles == Plane_2.transform.eulerAngles)
        {
            Debug.Log("THEY MATCH");
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** the answer for rotation does not work for all instances. For example if the object is flipped or has rotation in negative axis. This is what I did for the time being:

```
float diff = Quaternion.Angle(transform.rotation, target.rotation);
        // Return true if both values are smaller than the offset.
        return dist <= offset_position && ((diff <= offset_rotation && diff >= 0) || (diff <= (90+offset_rotation) && diff >= 90) || (diff <= (180+offset_rotation) && diff >= 180) || (diff <= (270+offset_rotation) && diff >= 270) || (diff <= 360 && diff >= (350+offset_rotation)));
```

I do not know if there is any better way to do this.

Comment: *"Exact position/rotation as the second static plane. It does not matter if the positions and rotations match or not"* Which one is it now? Do you want to check that they are the exact same position or does it not matter if they match?

Comment: Sorry for that. I will change my question.

Comment: @MathewHD I did think of Distance but that works fine for calculating positions. Rotations is the issue with it isn't it?

Comment: No it should work with both, because in the end your eulerAngles is just a Vector3 as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the equals operator [`==`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-operator_eq.html), will fail if the 2 `Vector3` are further away then **0.00001**.

Instead you can use [`Vector3.Distance()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html) and then compare the `float` you get with an `offset` instead of each other directly.

**CompareTransform Method:**

```cs
public float offset;

// Compares 2 Transforms position and rotations.
private bool CompareTransform(Transform current, Transform target) {
    // Gets the distance between 2 positions.
    float dist = Vector3.Distance(current.position, target.position);

    // Get the difference between the 2 rotations.
    float diff = Vector3.Distance(current.eulerAngles, target.eulerAngles);

    // Return true if both values are smaller than the offset.
    return dist <= offset && diff <= offset;
}
```

---

You can now use the method  to compare both `Transform` Components in your `Update` Method.

**Function Call:**

```cs
private void Update() {
    if(CompareTransform(this.transform, Plane_2.transform)) {
        Debug.Log("Both planes match position with given offset.");
    }
}
```

---

You can alternatively use [`Quaternion.Angle()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Angle.html) to get the angle between the 2 rotations and then compare the `float` you get with your `offset` again.

**Quaternion.Angle Alternative:**

```cs
// Get the angle between the 2 rotations.
float angle = Quaternion.Angle(transform.rotation, target.rotation);
```

Comment: Hey thank you for a detailed answer! I do not understand the concept of offset in your code. For me the positions/rotations match if I keep the offset around >= 100. Basically the values of the axes should come around the target value to match. This is the purpose of the offset.

Comment: The purpose for the offset is like you said to still get a true even if they aren't perfectly the same and that is also what it does in my code I'm just comparing the distacnes betwenn the rotations and positions with an offset and then seeing if it's smaller or bigger to check if they are equal to each other.

Comment: Did the answer solve your problem btw? Because if it did I would really appreciate it, if you would mark it as the answer so others won't attempt to add answers to a question that has already been solved.

Comment: Ah perfect thank you. My second plane was rotated 180 degrees so it was confusing. :D

Comment: `if the 2 Vector3 are nearly the same` to be exact if the distance is smaller than `0.00001` .. just adding for completeness ;)

Comment: @derHugo Will add it to my answer thanks for the information :D

Comment: [`Vector3` operator `==`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-operator_eq.html) ;)

Comment: Unfortunately does not completely work for rotation. Could you please see my question again?

Comment: @Tharres It would be nice if you could make the current problem a new question as your original question was about comparing 2 rotations and positions and not about comparing 2 rotations if one of them is possibly flipped.